# writeUTF method is displaying error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a chat server. I am beginner in it. I have written some lines of code and using writeUTF method to send data to server but it is displaying error on client code. On server side it is working fine. Code of my client machine is

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class Client
{
    Socket client=new Socket("127.0.0.1",35000);
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeUTF("tha");
    dos.close();
    client.close();
}
```

can sombody please tell me the answer? 
the error messages are
 expected
illegal start of type 
on writeUTF method

Comment: I don't see an error displayed, can you show it to us?

Comment: Is 127.0.0.1 really the address of the server?

Comment: I am using my computer as a server and as a client @StephaneM

Answer (score 1):

> the error messages are "expected illegal start of type" on writeUTF method.

The problem is that you have put statements into a class body.

The those statements need to go into a method.  Your text book or tutorial should explain this.